# Swift-YouTube-Player : Not able to read available videos

Tags: swift, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player to read youtube videos in my app such as this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bw0tjdBgKBY

With a WEB browser it works well, but using the library, a message appears saying :

> This video is unavailable

I can see the video preview before playing the video, but when the video starts the message appears in my app.

Is there video contents locked by youtube when using this kind of library ? 
Every video published by FIFATV seems to be unavailable using this library...

[image]

I'm setting the video in the youtubePlayer like that :

```
youtubePlayerView.loadVideoURL(URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBTFz-9bozc"))
```

Other videos not from FIFATV are working.

Any idea concerning the problem ?

Comment: Same here , but same video is playing in android

Comment: @krishankumar you using a youtube player too ?

Comment: Yes,  i am using it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what happened to your streaming, you should add another parameter, so following the [Swift-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player) example correct this part adding the `origin` parameter:

### Swift-YouTube-Player/YouTubePlayerExample/YouTubePlayerExample/ViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func loadVideo(sender: UIButton) {
        playerView.playerVars = [
            "playsinline": "1",
            "controls": "0",
            "showinfo": "0",
            "origin": "https://www.youtube.com"
        ]
        playerView.loadVideoID("wQg3bXrVLtg")
    }
```

If  you add this parameter the framework avoid to use a blank page as source origin of the streaming and use your value, infact if you take a look to the official sources:

### YTPlayerView.m

```
if (![playerVars objectForKey:@"origin"]) {
        self.originURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"];
    } else {
        self.originURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [playerVars objectForKey:@"origin"]];
    }
```

Now you should have a message like:

***"This video contains content from FIFA, who has blocked it from display on this website or application. Watch on YouTube"***

Reading the [Youtube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en) you can put also `http://example.com` as value:

[image]

where searching for `enablejsapi` you will find:

[image]

Unfortunately,speaking about the YT iOS framework you can search this parameter but you'll find that **it's already setted to 1** inside the file **player.js** and if you'll try to set it inside the `playerVars` nothing it will happen.

**So it's remain (for now..) an Youtube iOS framework bug**, probably not properly a bug but YT staff should add to their policies another rule for the iOS content flux, same thing maded for VEVO and a part of UMG content if I remember (and there are also other bugs yet unresolved..)

Comment: but same video is playing in android SDK

Comment: i know , i am saying that same video is playing in Android SDK but not in iFrame (This SDK uses iFrame internally ) but both are given by google.It may be possible that i am wrong, Please correct me.

Comment: The YT servers knows when the iFrame is executed by a mobile or web, and when it comes from iOS or Android. If you read the iOS sources you can easily understand that this SDK make only like a "wrapper" for the iFrame API. So, as I supposed, it should be an internal policy that should be setted in these servers to enable just the FIFATV flux (because other like VEVO works well)..

Comment: that is what i am asking , as you have mentioned that there is an  internal policy that should be setted in these servers to enable just the FIFATV flux then why it is playing in android SDK. Please pardon me to bother you again.

Comment: I cannot answer for Android, I'ven't yet analized the android SDK. Anyway, for the servers are two different things (iOS from Android calls). If the iFrame don't work this should be a web policy, if you make calls from the iOS SDK this is an iOS call, same thing for Android. I think the answer is always inside these servers because there aren't other flags to set or enable  according to the official APIs.

Comment: so , do we need to buy music and proof that we bought it and use it in youtube video ?